# My current domain name gives a 400 Bad Request and other times loads just fine

Tags: nginx, laravel-4, dns, digital-ocean, http-status-code-400

So I some how got suckered into setting up a server on Digital Ocean and I am not quite qualified to do so but I have to figure it out.

I am using Laravel Forge to manage it and when I originally created it, it worked fine if I went to www.mywebsite.com but it seems to completely randomly change between working just fine and returning a 400 Bad Request nginx error. How can I accomplish resolving this issue? I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Edit: It seems that the DNS might still be pointed at the old server AND the new server? Whaat?

Comment: What are to defined routes?
What is the error message saying?
Is there an example I can see?

Comment: @Pelevet The routes as in laravel's routes file? Or DNS routes? http://www.detroitpeoplemover.net/ is the URL. Currently it's showing me this: "400 Bad Request | nginx" Sometimes, however, it forwards to the correct site which says something like "Welcome to the site" or something just printed to the screen in plain text. I'm not sure why sometimes it's one way and sometimes its another.

Comment: it seem like its working fine.. if you just moved from one server to another and did some configuration in the domain, give it some time to settle..And this has nothing to do with laravel..

Comment: Okay. I'll trust you. IT just seems to bounce back and forth which I don't quite understand? Would you mind checking it again in a bit and seeing if it's the same?

Comment: sure i already did refreshed it like 100 times. works like a charm..

Comment: Thanks. I hope it starts working for me. It was working for a bit earlier but not anymore. :(

Comment: day 3 still works! just feedbacking :p

Comment: Thanks @Pelevet. It seems to be working for me too. I just have to fix the .htaccess in order to forward non www to www and I'll be good to go. I really appreciate you helping me!